# How do I represent "9 AM EST" in Joda Time?

Tags: java, jodatime

Joda Time appears to handle the notion of having some of the information about a particular instant in time, but not all of it. For instance, the `LocalTime` class can represent the time "9:43:17 AM", and the `LocalDate` class knows about "July 7th, 2010" regardless of time zone.

But I have a pile of Instants, and I want to know which of them happened after "9 AM PST." That is to say, in PST, which of the input instants happened after 9 AM?

Can this be expressed easily in Joda Time? Bonus points if there's a way to parse a string like "9:43 AM EST"

Comment: Do you mean "the time component is after 9AM, regardless of date", or "the instant is after 9AM today"?

Comment: I mean the time component. An instant that was equivalent to "1 AM tomorrow" should be false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the "partial" time classes (and indeed the `PartialTime` interface that they implement) can represent a timezone.  That's what the documentation says.  So you **have to** represent the timezone separately.

As a consequence,

- you need to do the "after 9am EST" calculation by hand, and
- you can't directly parse a string like "9:43 AM EST".

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I didn't find a satisfactory answer with code. So this is what I did: (sorry, I kept it in Scala)

```
def nineAMOfDate(date: DateTime) = {
  new DateTime(date.getYear, date.getMonthOfYear, date.getDayOfMonth, 9, 0, DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York"))
}
```

This will use Eastern Prevailing Time as far as I understand.